# Fetch the data from the CSV files in ruby and Order the Data in DESC?

Tags: ruby, csv

This is my CSV file values

```
Name , Sales
Randy, 200
Robin, 502
Randy, 200
Raj,   502
Randy, 500      
Robin, 102      
Mano,  220
Raj,   502
Randy, 285
Robin, 385
Randy, 295
Raj,   596
```

I need this output

```
   Name  Sales  Rank 
   Randy 1596   1
   Raj   1354   2
   Robin  988   3
   Mano   860   4
```

When I used the `max and most` it shows only the maximum value and the most is not working for me. I need help with this please anyone help me with this
Thank you

```
cust = Hash.new

  CSV.foreach(("./test.csv"), headers: true, col_sep: ",") do |row|

    cust.store(row["Name"],row["Sales"])   
  end
  
  print cust
```

I'm currently tried with Hash but it saving the last data

Comment: Clarification is definitely needed as to what you have done so far.

Comment: I  tried with array

Comment: I'm currectly trying with the Hash but it is storing the last data

Comment: Your CSV needs to have titles in the first row if you want row['Name'] to work. Right now row['Name'] is nil

Comment: Yes I have name and sales row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need column names in the CSV if you want to use the `row["COL"]` csv syntax.
Additionally you need to use `+=` not `=` to add them up. Right now you're just overwriting the value every time.

```
Name,Sales
Randy, 200
Robin, 502
Randy, 200
Raj,   502
Randy, 500      
Robin, 102      
Mano,  220
Raj,   502
Randy, 285
Robin, 385
Randy, 295
Raj,   596
```

```
require 'csv'
cust = Hash.new

CSV.foreach(("./data.csv"), headers: true, col_sep: ",") do |row|
  # if key isn't in hash start it at 0
  unless cust.keys.include?(row["Name"])
    cust[row["Name"]] = 0 
  end
  # add the sales (.to_i converts to integer)
  cust[row["Name"]] += row["Sales"].to_i
end

puts "Name Sales Rank"
# Sort by the value not the key. Make it negative so it's descending
# not ascending. 
# each_with_index is just a nice way to count them
cust.sort_by{|k,v| -v}.each_with_index do |(name, sales), i|
  puts "#{name} #{sales} #{i+1}"
end
```

Produces:

```
Raj 1600 1
Randy 1480 2
Robin 989 3
Mano 220 4
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let's create a file containing that information.

```
str =<<~_
Name , Sales
Randy, 200
Robin, 502
Randy, 200
Raj,   502
Randy, 500      
Robin, 102      
Mano,  220
Raj,   502
Randy, 285
Robin, 385
Randy, 295
Raj,   596
_
```

```
FNAME = 'f.csv'
```

```
File.write(FNAME, str)
  #=> 157
```

CSV files have a fixed *column separator* (string). Conventionally, the separator would be a comma, in which case the content of this file would appear as follows:

```
Name,Sales
Randy,200
Robin,502
Randy,200
Raj,502
Randy,500      
Robin,102      
Mano,220
Raj,502
Randy,285
Robin,385
Randy,295
Raj,596
```

Alternatively, the separator could be `", "`, but that is not the separator for all your rows. The first line contains a space before the comma and some other lines contain two or more spaces after the comma. You therefore should use a comma (the default) as the column separator and then, where needed, strip away beginning and trailing spaces of what is left.

We may first open the file to create a `CSV` instance.

```
require 'csv'
```

```
csv = CSV.open(FNAME, headers: true)
  #=> #<CSV io_type:File io_path:"f.csv" encoding:UTF-8 lineno:0 col_sep:",
        " row_sep:"\n" quote_char:"\"" headers:true>
```

We would find that `csv.class #=> CSV` and `csv.headers #=> true`. The latter merely confirms that we have stipulated that the file has headers. The headers themselves are not returned because nothing in the file has yet been read. Once the first line after the header has been read `csv.headers` will return an array of the headers. You don't need `col_sep: ","` because the default column separator is a comma.

We now read the file and compute a hash of interest.

```
h = csv.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |csv_row, h|
  name, sales = csv.headers
  h[csv_row[name].strip] += csv_row[sales].to_i
end
  #=> {"Randy"=>1480, "Robin"=>989, "Raj"=>1600, "Mano"=>220}
```

As `CSV.included_modules.include?(Enumerable) #=> true`, [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) enumerates elements of `csv`, which are instances of [CSV_Row](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html) (values of the block variable `csv_row`) and creates a *counting hash* with the form of the method [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument (the *default value*) and no block. Note that in the calculations `name #=> "Name "` and `sales #=> " Sales"`.

We may now retrieve the headers:

```
name, sales = csv.headers.map(&:strip)
  #=> ["Name", "Sales"]
```

It is a good idea to close the file:

```
csv.close
```

though the method `CSV#close` is not documented.

---

We may now manipulate `h` and `headers` to suit requirements. For example, we may compute the following:

```
names, all_sales = h.sort_by { |name, sales| -sales }
                    .map { |name,sales| [name, sales.to_s] }
                    .transpose
  #=> [["Raj", "Randy", "Robin", "Mano"], ["1600", "1480", "989", "220"]]
```

```
max_name_len  = [name.size, names.max_by(&:size).size].max
  #=> 5
max_sales_len = [sales.size, all_sales.max_by(&:size).size].max
  #=> 4
```

```
RANK_NAME = "Rank"
max_rank_len  = [RANK_NAME.size, names.size].max
  #=> 4
```

and then present the results in a nicely-formatted way.

```
puts name.ljust(max_name_len) + ' ' + sales.rjust(max_sales_len) +
  ' ' + RANK_NAME.rjust(max_sales_len)
(0..names.size-1).each { |i| puts names[i].ljust(max_name_len) + ' ' +
  all_sales[i].rjust(max_sales_len) + ' ' + (i+1).to_s.rjust(max_rank_len) }
```

This displays the following.

```
Name  Sales Rank
Raj    1600    1
Randy  1480    2
Robin   989    3
Mano    220    4
```

See [String#ljust](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-ljust) and [String#rjust](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-rjust). One may alternatively use [String#%](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-25) or [Kernel#sprintf](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

---

`CSV` has built-in *converters* (and *header converters*). If one writes:

```
csv = CSV.open(FNAME, headers: true, converters: :integer)
```

all of the values in the body of the file would be converted to integers. Unfortunately, that would convert the values of the `name` field to integers as well as the values of the `sales` field, which is not what we want. We can, however, create a *custom converter* to convert only `sales` values to integers. This is done as follows.

```
proc = ->(s) { s.match(/ *\d+ */) ? s.to_i : s }
csv = CSV.open(FNAME, headers: true, converters: proc)
```

We may then change `csv_row[sales].to_i` to `csv_row[sales]`:

```
h = csv.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |csv_row, h|
  name, sales = csv.headers
  h[csv_row[name].strip] += csv_row[sales]
end
  #=> {"Randy"=>1480, "Robin"=>989, "Raj"=>1600, "Mano"=>220}
```

If there were multiple custom converters we would write:

```
CSV.open(FNAME, headers: true, converters: [proc1, proc2,...])
```

where `proc1`, `proc2`,... are the procs that implement the custom converters. If there is just one custom converter, as here, we can write `converters: proc` or `converters: [proc]`.

---

Lastly, if you're a bit rusty working with CSV files you could simply treat the file as an ordinary file:

```
headers, *body = File.readlines(FNAME)
                     .map { |s| s.strip.split(/ *, */) }
  #=> [["Name", "Sales"],
  #    ["Randy", "200"], ["Robin", "502"], ["Randy", "200"],
  #    ["Raj", "502"], ["Randy", "500"], ["Robin", "102"],
  #    ["Mano", "220"], ["Raj", "502"], ["Randy", "285"],
  #    ["Robin", "385"], ["Randy", "295"], ["Raj", "596"]]
```

Therefore:

```
headers
  #=> ["Name", "Sales"]
body
  #=> [["Randy", "200"], ["Robin", "502"], ["Randy", "200"],
  #    ["Raj", "502"], ["Randy", "500"], ["Robin", "102"],
  #    ["Mano", "220"], ["Raj", "502"], ["Randy", "285"],
  #    ["Robin", "385"], ["Randy", "295"], ["Raj", "596"]]
```

```
h = body.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |(name, sales),h|
  h[name] += sales.to_i
end
  #=> {"Randy"=>1480, "Robin"=>989, "Raj"=>1600, "Mano"=>220}
```

and then procede as before.